# Do script block rendering in safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charSet="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  works
  <script defer>
    alert()
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, this page will display "works" and then show alert box, but in safari 11.1, it will be blank, then show alert box.

Do script block rendering in safari?

Answer (score 1):

The `defer` element according to [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) say:

> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

It also states that:

> This attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

Meaning that it wouldn't work with the code you supplied, since a) it is inline and b) it is not a DOM element.

Although the symptoms seem to be similar with your code, when I used a `document.createElement` to add items to the DOM in an external file, all browsers functioned the same.

I would put it down to an anomaly between browser engines. Then again when adding and the DOM and using an external file there was no issue.

Here is the code, I mentioned the `document.createElement` before, but that is only part of it, you have to append it to your document as well.

```
alert()

let x = document.createElement('p');
x.innerHTML = "Testing"
document.body.appendChild(x);
```

Comment: when i use document.createElement, the issue still

Comment: Did you add the object to the your body with .appendchild? I will update the code I used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way script not prevent page rendering in safari?

Comment: The way I generally do it is by having only functions in my js file and then call them based on events on my page. That way I control when a function runs. Is that what you are after, or do you want things to run after a certain amount of time?